# How to open a Component in an onPress call?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

So basically I have a Screen in my app that has a Button in it and this button should open a Modal that is also a selfmade component in the same screen js file.

I am setting the state visible in the screen and the button has an onPress handler that toggles the visible state (false/true).

I dont know how to display my own modalComponent when the button is clicked.

btw using react-native-modal

Own modal component:

```
class PhasenModal extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Modal isVisible={this.props.visible}>
          <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Text>I am a modal</Text>
          </View>
        </Modal>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

In my ScreenView :

```
<Button
  buttonStyle={styles.phaseButton}
  title="Choose"
  onPress={() => this.phasenModalHandler()}
/>
```

The onPress fnct:

```
phasenModalHandler() {
  this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible });
  if (this.state.visible) {
    return <PhasenModal visible={this.state.visible} />;
  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```

I expect the button to show the Modal but it doesnt show anything ,
the state gets toggled correctly tho it switched from false to true.

I guess my onPress fctn is wrong becaus I dont know how to render the component.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you return from your event handler will not be rendered, so you could instead use the `visible` value in your state to conditionally render the `PhasenModal` component.

```
class ScreenView extends Component {
  state = {
    visible: false
  };

  phasenModalHandler = () => {
    this.setState(({ visible }) => ({ visible: !visible }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Button
          buttonStyle={styles.phaseButton}
          title="Choose"
          onPress={this.phasenModalHandler}
        />
        {this.state.visible && <PhasenModal />}
      </>
    );
  }
}

class PhasenModal extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Modal isVisible>
          <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Text>I am a modal</Text>
          </View>
        </Modal>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks at least i get a modal shown now but there are few problems. 1. It always shows now across all screens, because the value of isVisible is set to true but it needs to be controlled by my screen like I said above this.props.visible. 2. I put a button in the modal to close it,  do u have any idea how a fnctn to close it could look like? because I cant go setState in the modal component becase my state is managed in the screen.

Comment: @yesIamFaded You could pass the `phasenModalHandler` method as a prop called  e.g. `toggle` to the `PhasenModal` component and call that when you click the close button.

Comment: Ok seems to work for me obviously I need to do some fine tuning but THANKS for your solution.

Comment: Would you mind to explain to me why we need the : "" <>    </> ""  in the  />
        {this.state.visible && <PhasenModal />}
      </>

Comment: @yesIamFaded Great! You're welcome. A component needs only one top level element, and `<></>` is called a [Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) and will not render anything in the DOM. You could e.g. use a top level `<div></div>` instead if you prefer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191655/discussion-between-yesiamfaded-and-tholle).